# Managing source files in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I was moving some files around in an Xcode project and deleted some files in finder (I know).  I've broken my project and now I can't figure out how to fix it.

At the moment I'm getting an `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` error when trying to build.  The files however, are actually in the project and physically in the project directory.  I added them to compiled sources, but I'm still getting the same error.

I don't understand how Xcode manages the source files and I haven't found any good information on how to troubleshoot these problems.  Googling basically tells me to not delete files (too late) and I can't find anything in the Mac Developer documents.

How can I get my source files back in order so I can build this project?

**EDIT:** I noticed this in compiled sources:

[image]
The files that are causing the problems are the ones that don't have "...in Worker" next to them (Worker is the name of the project).

Answer (score 0):

When you try to delete a file, then two options pop up: Remove reference or Move to trash.

1. If you select Remove reference, then you file is present in the project file directory. You just need to goto finder->your project and add that missing file.
2. If you select move to trash, then goto Trash, select file, right click and select put back.

If still you are getting error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64", then closely observe the error, in the last line of error, some variable name/class name is written there which is missing. Either that variable is declared multiple time or not declared.

Comment: Declared multiple times? Like in a header without include guards?

Comment: Yes, also sometimes a variable is declared in common function class. And that common function class is inherited multiple times which results into cyclic inheritance. To avoid such kind, inherit/include the common function class in pch file.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how Xcode manages the source files

It really doesn't. You add files to the project, and Xcode updates the project file with the fact that those files are in the project and their location on disk. If files go missing from the project (Xcode can't find them because you moved or deleted them), those file names are displayed in red in the project navigator.

So, start by looking for red filenames in the project navigator. Those are files you need to put back. If you're not sure where they were before, or if you want to move them to some other location, you can also just delete them from the project and then add them again.

> At the moment I'm getting an Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: error

That may mean that you've forgotten to add some file or other to a specific target. If you select a source file in the project navigator and look at the file inspector, there's a section called "Target Membership" where you can see which targets the file is part of. If you've just added a file to the project, make sure that the checkboxes next to all the targets that depend on that file are checked.

Comment: That's some good information, but the files are actually in the project and the targets are correct.  Still not working.  This is one of the errors: "MASClipAddVertex(double, double, MASClipPolyline*)", referenced from:
      -[MASPolyline clip:] in MASPolyline.o

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Build Phrases -> Copy Bundle Resources" and remove those files which are represented in Red color text.

Also make sure that in your project navigator you should remove those missing files as you deleted them physically from your project directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: None of the files are actually missing.  They were replaced with... I can't remember.  I shouldn't have messed with it.